# React-Native-Webview PDF File Crashes Application

Tags: react-native, http-headers, react-native-webview

Package: React-Native-Webview @ ^6.11.1 (also tried updating to latest with same results)

React Native Webview Crashes our application when attempting to load a PDF file into the browser.  We have tackled this issue before in another website and implemented URL checking to look for `.pdf` in the url and handle that use case appropriately.  Unfortunately this does not appear to catch this use case because the url does not contain `.pdf` as you can see in the crash logs output below.

I am reaching out on Stack Overflow because I do not know how to check the file type of the http request being made within the webview if that file type is not present on url.

I know that this site is an Angular site after reviewing the code; and the click action of the angular app is triggering the following method: `vm.retrieveDocument(content.fileId, content.fileName)`

This website does function as expected and downloads the attached pdf when viewing in the Google Chrome browser on Android.

IOS functions as expected because IOS supports viewing the PDF file in the webview.

Google has directed me repeatedly to checking the url for .pdf, which we have implemented; but I have yet to come across guidance for a url that contains no file extension.

```
2020-05-29 13:48:51.500 9282-9282/com.COMPANY.EmployeeApp.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.COMPANY.EmployeeApp.android, PID: 9282
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:https://COMPANY.WEBSITE.com/da0d14e9-2210-4598-ad68-de99b4e600b0
        at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.<init>(DownloadManager.java:461)
        at com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewManager$2.onDownloadStart(RNCWebViewManager.java:190)
        at Do.handleMessage(PG:154)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Does the file request returns the Content-type HTTP header?

Comment: Currently I do not know of a way to access the HTTP Request headers within the React-Native-Webview library.

Comment: I have a similar problem in my React-Native app.

I have some API request that returns an object like `{"mimeType": "application/pdf","content": "JVBERi...`
After that, the app closes immediately